# Count of one row only once based on another row

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble describing what I want to do but the example is the best explanation:

Below is MOSTLY what I want to do but there is another column: Date and I want to count each date only once per store

```
SELECT key,COUNT(*) AS 'cnt',NAME FROM myTable GROUP BY key
```

So excluding any data that is not relevant lets say I have:

```
  KEY  |  DATE
--------------------

  A    |  2019-06-01*
  A    |  2019-06-01
  A    |  2019-06-02*
  A    |  2019-06-03*
  B    |  2019-06-01*
  B    |  2019-06-01
  B    |  2019-06-01
  B    |  2019-06-02*
  C    |  2019-06-01*
  C    |  2019-06-02*
```

I'd like to get

```
A | 3
B | 2
C | 2
```

Counting the first unique date only for each Key(marked with the *).
Any simple way to pull this off that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT KEY, COUNT(DISTINCT DATE) AS 'cnt' FROM myTable GROUP BY KEY;
```

Comment: Ah, I knew it was going to be simple. Perfect, thanks.